# Do not proxy a request if location or directory match

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, reverse-proxy

Let's say that I want to proxy requests to `proxytest.xxx.com` through http://somedomain.com/

**except** http://proxytest.xxx.com/local/ and all files under `/var/www/proxytest/somedir`
(2 distinct rules - one based on *Location* the other on *Directory*)

How would one go about exempting a *Location* or *Directory* from being proxied?

---

At the moment I have the following code that is able to proxy the requests, but that's about it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName proxytest.xxx.com
    ProxyPass / http://somedomain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://somedomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Excluding paths

Paths can be excluded by replacing the remote URL with an exclamation mark. For example, you could exclude the path /internal/execluded while continuing to provide access to the remainder of /internal with the following pair of ProxyPass directives:

```
ProxyPass /internal/excluded !
ProxyPass /internal http://internal.example.com/public
```